# can I have a global variable in python without declaring it as global?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, counter

I want some sort of a global state that maintains the current number, as well as a function to generate the next number.

I can write a generator to give me the next number.

```
 def gen(self, n):
    yield n
    yield n + 1
```

but what is a clean way to maintain its state? I do not want to simply have a global variable. Is there a better way to do this? or is that my only option?

I tried to make a class like this:

```
class Count:
"""
Represents the counter which
generates variables
"""

def __init__(self, curr=0):
    """
    :param curr: the current integer
    """
    self.curr = curr

def gen(self):
    """
    A generator for the next
    number
    :return: generator
    """
    self.curr += 1
    yield self.curr
    yield self.curr + 1
```

but this will not work, because every time I create Count(), it will reset my counter which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, to eliminate the `global` counter you could create a closure for you variable and return a function that increments it.

The original function `counter` is called only once, consecutive calls simply increment the counter:

```
def count(n):
    c = n
    def incr():
        nonlocal c
        c += 1
        print(c)
        return c
    return incr
```

`count` is initialized with some state `n` and `incr` references that state in consecutive calls:

```
>>> f = count(2)
>>> f()
3
>>> f()
4
>>> f()
5
```

Comment: Okay, so I still need to call count(2) on top of my file. It seems very similar to if I were to maintain a global variable, right?

Comment: @Lana You'll *always* have global variables, the difference is that the counter in this case is *enclosed* inside the function. With a global counter `n = 20` if someone changes `n` it'll mess up your counting, with closures that can't be done.

Comment: Oh. Okay, then this is what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain state across multiple instances of `Count`, then use a variable in the class scope, and reference it with the `Count.` prefix, like this:

```
class Count:
    curr = 0

    def __init__(self, startWith = None):
        if startWith is not None: Count.curr = startWith - 1

    def gen(self):
        while True:
            Count.curr += 1
            yield Count.curr
```

Note that if you want to maintain state, the constructor should allow for the possibility to *not* reset the counter, but leave it untouched.

As a side note, you might be interested in letting the generator generate a never ending series as shown above.

Here is how you could use the above class:

```
# Get generator that starts with 2
gen = Count(2).gen();

print (next(gen)); # -> 2
print (next(gen)); # -> 3
print (next(gen)); # -> 4

# Get a generator that continues ...
gen2 = Count().gen();

print (next(gen2)); # -> 5

# We can still use the previous generator also:

print (next(gen)); # -> 6

# Start with 0:

gen3 = Count(0).gen();

print (next(gen3)); # -> 0

# Other generators follow suit:

print (next(gen)); # -> 1
print (next(gen2)); # -> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the next(generator) function.

```
def num_gen():
    n=1
    while n:
        yield n
        n += 1
```

Then

```
>>my_gen = num_gen()
>>next(my_gen)
1
>>next(my_gen)
2
```

And so forth.  Whenever a generator yields a value, the state of the generator is stored so that it can resume execution later.

Comment: Okay, so I'm confused then. This "my_gen = num_gen()" goes on top of the file, so it seems to me the same as a global variable, no?